What's the name of the oily greasy stuff they put on artillery shells to preserve them?
Someone in a youtube video was talking about it, and they didn't know the name of the stuff either.
It doesn't matter, but I can't stand it when I can't remember something  at the tip of my tongue.

Солидол/grease/solid oil

Were you looking for Cosmoline?

Cosmoline is the genericized trademark for a common class of brown, wax-like petroleum-based corrosion inhibitors, typically conforming to United States Military Standard MIL-C-11796C Class 3.[1] They are viscous when freshly applied, have a slight fluorescence, and solidify over time with exposure to air. The main ingredient in cosmoline is aliphatic petroleum solvent, which is volatile and evaporates over time.[2] [Wikipedia:Cosmoline][1]


And somewhat toxic, according to the Car Talk guys.

@Spencer - RIP Car Talk guys. Or at least Tom.
